# Java, False && False work around

Tags: java

I have tried searching for this but I don't really know how to word it to see if anyone else has posted an answer.

However, I am making a chess game and an AI to go along with it which is extremely difficult and my question is when I check if two pieces are on the same team I have to do `(atLoc.isWhite() && selected.isWhite()) || (!atLoc.isWhite() && !selected.isWhite())` which is long winded is there an operator that allows False && False to give out True as well as True && True to give out true, sorry if you don't understand.

Comment: Isn't `atLoc.isWhite() == selectec.isWhite()` quite obvious?

Comment: enum Team {White, Black}

selected.isSameTeam(atLoc)

Comment: Don't use `isWhite()`.  Define an enum type `Color` that has `BLACK` and `WHITE`.  Then define a method `getColor()` so that you can do simply `atLoc.getColor() == selected.getColor()`.

Comment: "... an operator that allows False && False to give out True"? I think you're very confused about the rules of Boolean algebra. This is like saying "I want 0 * 0 to equal 1."

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the inverse of XOR :

```
!(atLoc.isWhite() ^ selected.isWhite())
```

though, as Tom commented, what's wrong with :

```
atLoc.isWhite() == selected.isWhite()
```

Comment: @OliPro007 if you only have white and non-white (aka black) then you basically check if both are white (true == true) or not (false == false), i.e. "do they both return the same value?".

Comment: @OliPro007 if you are in the black team and the piece is black, both `isWhite()` calls would return false, and false==false is true.