# Javascript: false && false is false?

Tags: javascript, operators, boolean-logic

So, I've done some searching, looks like it hasn't been asked yet but I could be wrong.

Logically

```
false && false === true
false && true === false
true && false === false
true && true === true
```

**HOWEVER**

It does not seem like this is the case for `javascript`. I ran the above in the `console` and this is what I get from FireFox && Chrome:

```
false && false //console output: false
false && true //console output: false
true && false //console output: false
true && true //console output: true
```

I've already found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35941501/java-false-false-work-around) but seriously? Why? I would think this to be standard behavior.

It even says in [`Java` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) that `logical AND | &&`.

Comment: `false && false === true` Huh? Why do you think that?

Comment: Why would you look at Java documentation for why JavaScript (**a completely different language**) does something?

Comment: You're thinking of XOR

Comment: @SLaks Because I'm having one of those days when you've stared at a screen too long is why.

Comment: you're thinking of equivalent

Comment: @SLaks I can only speak for myself, but unconsciously I think I interpreted it as (false == false) = true.

Comment: @josh i think that's what i did too unfortunately

Answer (score 17, accepted):

false and false is false logically.

Comment: This is correct.  Only true && true == true.

Answer (score 6):

The result of an expression using the `&&` operator is determined based on these rules:

If the left side of the expression is "falsey", the expression will return the left side.

If the left side of the expression is "truthy", the expression will return the right side.

That's it. So in `false && false`, the left side is "falsey", so the expression returns the left side, `false`.

I've actually written a blog post about the [|| and &&](https://medium.com/@arnav_aggarwal/javascript-and-logical-operators-89b2ac3409f8) operators. It can explain what's going on in detail.

Answer (score 1):

every time you set a false expression with AND´s, the rest of the equation does not matter, since every expression must be TRUE for the result to be true.

false && true means:

are both equations valid? is "false" AND "true" true?
if any of these fail, then its false

another example:

true || (true && false)

in this case, you read like this:

is "true" true OR ... "true" AND "false" true?

the first one is evaluated as true, so there is no need to verify the second equation(since one of them is already true), in fact it does not. for optimization.

Answer (score 1):

the `&&` operator has a left-to-right associativity.

means if the first value is truthy (coercible to true) it will evaluate the second, if the second is truthy the third..until the last one that will be the result of the expression.

since the first element of the operator is falsy (coercible to false) the expression returns immediatly false.

[Operator precedence  MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)